# How to implement JsonField in django that has postgresql as backend?

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to implement JsonField in my django application running postgresql.Can I also have indexing on that Json Field so that I can have Mongo like features? Do I have to make use of sqlalchemy for this or django built-in ORM is suitable for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use google https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install [`django-jsonfield`](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield)

```
pip install jsonfield
```

and use it on your field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_json_field = JSONField()
```

It's just a `TextField` that serializes the json object to a python dictionary so **no you can't have an index on it nor can you make queries against your json field.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres (and don't care about compatibility with other DB engines) you should consider django's postgres fields

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

this should have much better performance than the ordinary jsonfield.

If DB compatibility is an issue and/or you want your field be readable/editable through django admin you might want to consider KeyValueField instead https://github.com/rewardz/django_model_helpers

Data is stored in DB like this

```
Name = abc
Age = 123
```

but returned to you like this

```
{"Name": "abc", "Age": "123"}
```

So if you make `db_index = True` you can do `field__contains="Age = 123"` but despite using db_index, its not fool proof because Age=1234 will also be returned by that query plus indexing text field is not usually recommended